# load a function after another has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having a problem with a equal height script that makes my 4 divs in a row equal heights. In one div, I have neosmart-stream, which loads my latest facebook post  inside the div. The other div's are supposed to match that one in height, the problem is is that the div heights match the tallest div that loads first, the one with the catalogue picture in it.

I want to be able to run the equal heights script after my facebook post has loaded.

Here is the link to the site: http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/
It applies to the 4 dark grey boxes underneath the rotating banner.

Here is the code for the equal heights:

```
<script>
  equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }
 });
}

$(window).load(function() {
  equalheight('.module');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  equalheight('.module');
});
  </script>
```

And here is the code for the facebook posts:

```
<div class="module">

<h1>News</h1>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/neosmart-stream/nss-includes/jquery.js'></script>
    
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/neosmart-stream/nss-core/jquery.neosmart.stream.js'></script>
    
<link href='http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/neosmart-stream/nss-core/core.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
<link href='http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/neosmart-stream/nss-content/themes/base/style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
<script type='text/javascript'>(function(window){window.onload=function(){jQuery(function(){jQuery('#nss').neosmartStream({introFadeIn:695,masonry:false,cache_time:60,theme:'base',path:'http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/neosmart-stream/',channel_group:'all',auto_refresh:true,auto_refresh_time:60})})}})(window);</script>
```

This is only some of the script, the facebook posts is a plugin. The four divs have the .module class

One has window.load(function()) and the other window.onload=function(), would these be conflicting? Is there a way I can set one to load so many milliseconds after the other?

Comment: You probably need to find the right `load` event to listen for and then run your script, but I'd suggest you post how the facebook post gets loaded so we can see what the options might be.

Comment: If that neosmart-stream supports events, you can listen for an on-loaded event and run the equal heights script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cheated a little with this one. the resize script activates when the page is loaded and when it is resized. So I added another event listener so that the script activates when the user scrolls down. This works since the boxes that resize are all below the fold on all screens and devices anyway (except for exceptionally long screens but how often do you come across them?)
I will have to figure it out properly but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your current code is, because you didn't post any snippets, but you might just want to try the classic table. Alternatively you might want to try setting every container to 100% height (css) and letting them float next to each other. If this doesn't solve your problem you might want to improve your question with some code snippets instead of letting us do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Facebook Javascript SDK then you should be able to use the async code and assign your height functions to run within the window.fbAsyncInit function. You may still need to wait, however, for CSS and stylings to be applied before you know the true height you are after.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
        channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
        status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can stuff your resizer script inside a `$(window).load` event, like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Your resize code
});
```

That way, the browser waits for the entire page (graphics, images, and iframes) to load before it fires your resizer script.

This means that if anything ever gets hung up--say, the user is on a 2G network, or an external resource fails to load--then your boxes will never resize. I've used it before, though, and it's an easy, quick fix, as long as you know the risks.